# Different results for same query in different Cassandra nodes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have 3 cassandra nodes, when I execute a `query`, 2 nodes are giving same response but 1 node is giving different response

Suppose I executed following `query`

```
select * from employee;
```

Node1 and Node2 are giving `2 rows` but Node3 is giving `0 rows(empty response)`

How to solve this issue

Comment: Would you please explain how are you doing nodewise query?

Comment: my 3 nodes are installed in 3 amazon instances, I am connecting to those instances then connecting to Cassandra and then querying

Comment: Each time you are connecting to one instance?And executing query?

Comment: I have a java application, which is already connected with those nodes, it runs continuosly... I got some issues in java, So i troubleshoot it.. While doing troubleshoot I connected to cassandra nodes then I realized that the issue is with cassandra nodes and they are giving different responses for different ndoes

Comment: Would you explain your configuration , replication factor and consistency? Are you sure that 3 nodes are connected in the cluster?

Comment: `'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '2'`

Comment: can you paste the changes you have done in the yaml or other files to create an amazon instance?

Comment: I haven't created the amazon instance, It was already created by other team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following steps, then problem was solved and now the data is in sync in all the 3 nodes

run the command `nodetool rebuild` on the instances and also

update `'replication_factor': '2'` to `'replication_factor': '3'`

Answer (score 1):

1.You are not using Network topology.
2.Your replication factor is 2.

Simple strategy : Use only for a single datacenter and one rack. SimpleStrategy places the first replica on a node determined by the partitioner. Additional replicas are placed on the next nodes clockwise in the ring without considering topology (rack or datacenter location).

Go to this link  :
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archDataDistributeReplication.html